# C libraries with a C++ solution

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I am working with an industrial solution containing GUI and HMI.
The solution is developed in C++, and im asked to interface the Hillstar Development Kit (for gesture recognition) with the C++ solution.
The thing is that the Hillstar Libraries (GestIC) and all the examples are developed in C.
So my question is how to implement these GestIC libraries in my C++ solution.

Thank you.

Comment: C++ code can call C libraries - what's the problem ?

Comment: Just use it. Only thing to ensure is that if the c headers don't have an `extern c` then you will need to add that at the point you include them in your files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ provides for calling C functions by declaring them via:

```
extern "C" {
  #include "my-C-code.h"
}
```

You can then call your C functions from C++ the same way you do from C.  This prevents the name mangling C++ would otherwise do, which would cause link errors.  This is essentially what Roony suggested in retrospect; but less cryptic.  As he also points out, there is no need to do this if the C file already has this statement; via preprocessor #ifdef statements that recognize C++ compilation.  This specifier turns off name mangling, and is apparently for function definitions and bodies only (although it won't interfere with preprocessor directives).  It seems that most other C code will work as is in C++.  Some C headers included via this extern will not compile - most notably ones that have functions with names which are reserved C++ keywords.

You can find out more about it here:["mixing c and cpp"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp) - from the "How can I include a non-system C header file in my C++ code?" section.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a problem using C functions in C++. You could just write a wrapper, which calls the specific library functions.

Comment: Is a wrapper required to call C from C++? I do know you have to write a wrapper to call C++ from C, but the other way around?

Comment: Will be cleaner and it depends on how he needs to interface his C++ solution with the C library (depending on the objects he wants to use)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. But like i said im new to c++,
can u explain how to write a wrapper and point me to the direction of some tutorials? thx

Comment: @OneManArmy You don't need a wrapper. You could literally just go `#include <stdlib.h>` and use C-like calls to `malloc()` or `free()` just fine. People write code to surround it because they don't like C's different style when used with C++ code.

Comment: Wrapper is a pretty general name for some functions that are designed to interface a higher level program with lower level program. E.g. I have written a driver for terminal, there I have function such as clear the io buffer, write a char, set baud rate, which are pretty low level. You want to write a program which communicates with the termial and you need functions such as initialize terminal and write string to terminal. The wrapper will take the input objects such as std::string, which is a class and write the string to the terminal performing the required processing.

Comment: @VermillionAzure I mentioned the wrapper, because I don't know how the solution and the library look like. It all depends on the implementation and how lol level the library is. In general I prefer to keep them separate.

Comment: As a note, `extern C` is needed if the C code will exist as separate object code that needs to be linked in. In this case, `extern C { /* C function include files */ }` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just include like all other includes.

```
#include "your library"
```

Now you can use it.

Comment: Might not work (and will most likely not if the C library is not C++ aware). Because of the C++ name mangling.

Comment: @axalis: A C library need not be *"C++ aware"* (what is that, anyway, and how did they implement C++-awareness before C++ was invented?). It is callable as-is. Only if you have a precompiled binary you need to link, you will have to accommodate for C's name decoration (e.g. by using `extern "C"`).

Comment: @Inspectable: Even if you don't have a precompiled binary, you will still (almost certainly) have to compile the C source code as C rather than C++.  It is possible to write code in the common subset of C and C++, but *very* little C is so written.  A "C++ aware" library, is one with `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" {"` guards in the header file itself (so the given answer works).  I suspect that by now, most C libraries do that.